how do I bake normals?
The Normals just bake weirdly and I don't know why
The_blender_file
Low Poly

High poly


As @John Eason mentioned above, first correct the inverted normals issue on the low poly model.
Next you need to Apply both Rotation and Scale transforms to both models.

In Object mode with the object selected use Ctrl+ A to open the Apply menu and choose the All Transforms option.

In the Shader Editor add a new Image Texture to bake to. Important: After adding the image texture node change the Color Space from the default sRGB to Non- Color data. This new Image Texture node must be selected before Baking.
Next Select first the high poly model then select the low poly model. (Because the low poly model was selected last it becomes the Active object).
In the Render panel set the Sampling > Render > Max Samples to a low value for quick baking time.
In the Bake panel set Bake Type to Normal. Enable Selected to Active with and Extrusion value of around 0.1 Then hit the Bake button.

The result should be something like in the screenshot below. To view the baked normals on the low poly model connect up the baked normals Image Texture node to the Normal Map node and plug into the Principled BDSF Normal input then change the viewport shading to Material Preview :


I've never baked Normals, but it may be because the low poly version has inverted normals in your file.
I've moved the versions apart in the image below and enabled the Face Orientation option on the Viewport Overlays menu. You can see that the high poly version is blue which is correct but the low poly one is red which means the normals are inverted.
Disable the high poly version in the outliner and select the low poly object. Go into Edit mode. Select All and hit Shift-N to recalculate the normals.

Try again and see if that fixes the problem.

Didn’t work, it just flips the weird map.

I've no idea in that case. Maybe someone else here can help.
